# Numbers-only JavaScript Firefox solution

Tags: javascript, firefox, keycode

I need some help cleaning up a popular piece of vanilla JavaScript code that causes issues in Firefox.

The following which/keyCode check seems to be about the most popular vanilla JS solution to allow only numbers into an `input` or `textarea`.

```
var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && ( charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
 return false;
}
return true;
```

Called via `onkeypress="return function(event);"` on the tag.

However, Firefox apparently binds arrow keys to `onkeypress` calls, rather than just to `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` like other browsers. This means that e.g. the left arrow key's `charCode` is `37`, but so is the `charCode` for % (shift+5). Even more importantly, it means that the arrow keys can't be used for navigation (moving the caret/text cursor left or right).

However, the difference is that the left arrow key has `keyCode 37`, while % has the `charCode` and `which` of `37` (as shown on http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html). So I was able to make the arrow keys work just fine by doing the following:

```
if (charcode > 31 && (charcode < 48 || charcode > 57)) {
 if (e.keycode && e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) {
  return true;
 }
  return false;
}
return true;
```

However, I feel like this is not the best or cleanest way to do it, and that there might be more keys handled differently by Firefox than just the arrow keys. What would be a cleaner vanilla JS solution or way to check for at least the arrow keys within this function?

Many thanks!

---

EDIT: I just figured that even though the code solves it for Firefox, it introduces a new problem for all other browsers, in that these now allow charCodes 37-40 (i.e. %) to be entered. Seems that instead of checking the `keyCode`, it would need to check the `charCode` or `which`, in otherwise the same manner.

Comment: Do you know that there is `<input type="number">`? Note that it is not so user-friendly to block certain keys: they might think their keyboard is broken. Also, they can still use copy/paste (even via the context menu), so you'll never be finished. Better just accept user input as it is, and validate it afterwards, maybe via a color indication or message near the input.

Comment: I do know that, but that wouldn't really suit the needs here. Also, from what I can tell, other non-character keys seem to behave just fine (afterall, it's only just the `onkeypress` that keeps them away from the input/textarea), not the `onkeydown` and `onkeyup`.It's obvious only numbers are to be entered, and in case they copy/paste anything, it will reset the text to a number anyways. However, the arrow navigation is a must and Firefox is a popular enough browser to have me worry about making sure at least those work well.

Comment: I found the original code because I was looking to do something with only the numbers being entered, not (just) to prevent other characters from being entered which the original code is intended to do (and also does for textareas instead of just inputs). However, using the original code was the easiest and clearest way for me to bring the issue to light and to ask for a better solution regarding that, as the solution is what would remain the same. Hope that clears it up. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against blocking certain keys, as I feel it degrades the user experience. But given that this is what you need, I would suggest to not rely on the `keyCode` property. Not only are there compatibility problems related to it, it also does not cover all ways input can be made, like with the mouse and context menu, and is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode):

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards.
>
> The `KeyboardEvent.keyCode` read-only property represents a system and implementation dependent numerical code

Instead I propose to use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event, which triggers on every change to the input value, and then to clean the value of non-digits, while putting the cursor at the place where the first offending character was found. This gives about the same user-experience, and has no bad effect on how arrow keys, backspace, delete, selection, ... etc work:

```js
document.querySelector('#num').addEventListener('input', function() {
    var badCharPos = this.value.search(/\D/);
    if (badCharPos == -1) return; // all OK
    // remove offending characters:
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.setSelectionRange(badCharPos, badCharPos);
});
```

```html
<input id="num">
```